# Display the recipient's name on an email sent via EWS

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I wish to pragmatically send an email from an exchange mailbox but when viewed in sent items in outlook display the contact name rather than the email address (like it does when sending via outlook).

I have attached a one drive link with an image example below, of viewing a sent item in outlook, when sent from outlook. My pragmatically sent email needs to replicate this.

How do I send an email using EWS so that the recipients name, and not only his address is shown?

https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=8F8BF7DFDA3B485C!443361&authkey=!AOiPcHZJePBNmJk&v=3&ithint=photo%2cjpg

Thanks a bunch

Comment: EmailAddresses in EWS have a `Name` property, did you set that?

Comment: Ah my friend you are right on the money :), thanks

Answer (score 0):

Set the `Name` property for the `EmailAddress` you use as recipient.